# Is my Paypal checkout flow Angular-Node secure?

Tags: node.js, paypal, checkout, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm developing a paypal checkout using the 'basic Smart Payment Buttons integration' and integrating it with server Node installing the 'checkout-server-sdk'.

I followed the documentations:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK

where they suggest to:

1. 'createOrder' starting from the client and calling the server
2. generating on the server an orderID and return it to the client
3. 'onApprove' send to the server the orderID and approve it on the server
4. return back to the client the response

I don't think it is a good flow.
Someone could:

1. start the payment
2. so the app create the order on the server taking the shoppingcart from db and elaborate a totalPrice of 100euros.
3. generete the orderID and send it back to the client
4. instead of approve this order, a 'bad user' could, in some way, send to the server another orderID that could correspond to a lower price (2euros)
5. so he could approve the payment of 2 euros

So I don't understand why we need to make the checkout jumping more times from client to server.
Or maybe am i doing something wrong on my checkoutflow ?

unfortunately I feel the Paypal documentation so unclear.

**checkout.component.html**

```
<!-- * here there is a form where i get shipment info, invoice info and so on ->

<!-- * PAYPAL SMART BUTTONS -->
<div>
    <div #paypal></div>
</div>
```

**checkout.component.ts**

```
onFormSubmit() {
  this.isFormSubmitted = true;
  // set paypal settings and show the paypal buttons
  this.paypalSetting(this.shippmentInfo, this.invoiceRequired, this.invoice, this.addressInvoice);
}

async paypalSetting(shipment, invoiceRequired, invoice, addressInvoice) {

  await paypal
    .Buttons({
      style: {
        size: 'responsive',
        label: 'pay',
      },
      experience: {
        input_fields: {
          no_shipping: 1,
        },
      },
      createOrder: async (data, actions) => {
        console.log('CREATE ORDER -->');
        var paypalOrderId;

        //generate new order
        await this.apiService.newOrder().toPromise().then(
          (res) => {
            console.log('ON CREATE: SUCCESSFULLY CREATED')
            paypalOrderId = res.order.paypalOrderId;

            // ????? someone here could change 'paypalOrderId' with another value !!!! 

            //I also would like to return the 'paypalOrderId' only here !!
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('ON CREATE: ERROR: ' + err);
            // how should i manage this error ? i should skip the flow to onError but HOW ?
          }
        );
        return paypalOrderId;
      },
      onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
        console.log('APPROVE ORDER -->');
        var paypalOrderId = data.orderID;

        console.log('ON APPROVE: save the order on server/DB')

        await this.apiService.saveOrder(shipment, invoiceRequired, invoice, addressInvoice, paypalOrderId).toPromise().then(
          (res) => {
            console.log('ON APPROVE: ORDER APPROVED')
            this.isPaid = true;
            //if isPaid i can show a 'success page'
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('ON APPROVE: ERROR: ' + err);
            this.isPaid = false;
          }
        );
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.log('ON ERROR: ' + err);
      },
    })
    .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
}
```

**Node api.js**

```
//* paypal
const paypal = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');
const payPalClient = require('../paypalManager');

router.post('/newOrder', tokenManager.verifyAccessToken, async function (req, res, next) {
  
  const idUser = req.userId;

  // I get the shoppingcart of the user 'idUser'

  // i calculate the total price
  var totalPrice;

  //* Call PayPal to set up a transaction
  let order;
  const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
  request.prefer("return=representation");
  request.requestBody({
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [{
      description: 'payment ecc..', /
      amount: {
        currency_code: 'EUR',
        value: totalPrice
      }
    }],
    application_context: {
      brand_name: "brand",
      shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING',
    },
  });
  let response = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);
  order = response;
  const paypalOrderId = order.result.id;

  // return a successful response to the client with the order ID
  return res.json({
    status: 200,
    order: {
      paypalOrderId: paypalOrderId,
    },
    message: "Paypal order sucessfully created",
  });

});


router.post('/saveOrder', tokenManager.verifyAccessToken, async function (req, res, next) {
  const idUser = req.userId;
  var paypalOrderId = req.body.paypalOrderId;

  try {
    connection.beginTransaction(async () => {
      try {
        // here i insert all the checkout infos in DB

        // confirm the queries executions
        connection.commit(async function (err) {
          if (err) {
            //return connection.rollback(function () {
            connection.rollback(function () {
              return next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error: " + err)); //! or error.message
            });
          }

          //* here i send the Emails to confirm the checkout
          
          //* capture/approve the order
          console.log('CAPTURING THE ORDER')
          var request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(paypalOrderId);
          request.requestBody({});
          // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
          let response = await payPalClient.client().execute(request);

          //*response
          return res.json({
            status: 200,
            message: "Paypal sucessfully approved",
          });

        });// end commit

      } catch (error) {
        connection.rollback(function () {
          return next(createError.Unauthorized("Sql query error " + error)); //! or error.message
        });
      }

    });// end transaction

  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }

});
```

**Node paypalManager.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * PayPal Node JS SDK dependency
 */
const checkoutNodeJssdk = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk');

/**
 * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment that has access
 * credentials context. Use this instance to invoke PayPal APIs, provided the
 * credentials have access.
 */
function client() {
  return new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment());
}

/**
 * Set up and return PayPal JavaScript SDK environment with PayPal access credentials.
 * This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use LiveEnvironment.
 */
function environment() {
  let clientId = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID;
  let clientSecret = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET;

  return new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.SandboxEnvironment(
    clientId, clientSecret
  );
}


module.exports = {
  client: client,
  prettyPrint: prettyPrint
};
```

Comment: Rephrase your questions, they don't make any sense

Comment: @Preston PHX i Rephrase  the questions with an example. I hope they are more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are "jumping" between the client and the server, is the approval by the payer has to happen on the client. The payer cannot give their approval on your server, they are not sitting on your server. They are using a client browser.

---

Regarding:

> a 'bad user' could, in some way, send to the server another orderID that could correspond to a lower price (2euros)

If this happens, your server should reject the undesired transaction, and not proceed with it. That's the point of having a server. Nothing happens unless your server OKs it.